# Google Maps API invisible map with shapes overlayed

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I have researched and researched the Map Styles and am confident that is the way to accomplish my goal, but execution has not worked. What I want is exactly what is below except i want either a solid color for the map or invisible map. The purpose is to use the shapes created to overlay onto a different map.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>LD Team - Google Maps Plotter</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAzr2EBOXUKnm_jVnk0OJI7xSosDVG8KKPE1-m51RBrvYughuyMxQ-i1QfUnH94QxWIa6N4U6MouMmBA"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //createGlobal Variables

    //for plot Address
    var map = null;
    var geocoder = geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();   //create function used to find Long, Lat based on city, state

    //forCircles
    var poly = [] ; 
    var circle; 

    //forBestFit Zoom
    var latlng = new Array();
    var numPoints = 0;

    var allowedBounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(49.5,-10), new GLatLng(59,2.6));

    //Initiatlize Google Map Control on Page Load
    function initialize() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas", 15, 15));

        //------------- Restricting the range of Zoom Levels -----------------------
        // Get the list of map types      
        var mt = map.getMapTypes();
        // Overwrite the getMinimumResolution() and getMaximumResolution() methods
        for (var i=0; i<mt.length; i++) {
        mt[i].getMinimumResolution = function() {return 2;}
        mt[i].getMaximumResolution = function() {return 11;}
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        /*------------- Restricting Viewing Bounds ---------------------------------
        // The allowed region which the whole map must be within
        //GLatLngBounds(sw?:GLatLng, ne?:GLatLng)
        var allowedBounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(-60.0525,178.0781), new GLatLng(70.3779,-169.4531));
        // Add a move listener to restrict the bounds range
        GEvent.addListener(map, "move", function() {
        checkBounds();
        });
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        /*------------- Mouse Hover Show/Hide Controls -----------------------------
        GMap2.prototype.hoverControls = function(opt_noCloseIw){
          var theMap = this;
          theMap.hideControls();
          GEvent.addListener(theMap, "mouseover", function(){
            theMap.showControls();
          });
          GEvent.addListener(theMap, "mouseout", function(){
            theMap.hideControls();
          });
          theMap.libraryCard = 19162;
        }
        GMap.prototype.hoverControls = GMap2.prototype.hoverControls;
        map.hoverControls();                                
        //------------- End Mouse Hover Show/Hide Controls-------------------------*/

        //map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl3D());         //add fancy 3D map controls (zoom, set center)
        //map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());           //add regular map controls (zoom, set center)           
        //map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());                //add fancy map controls (maptype option:  map, satellite, hybid)
        map.setMapType(G_PHYSICAL_MAP);                 //change Maptype to Terrian
        map.enableContinuousZoom();                         //smoothed zoom in and out
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(20.6328, 4.2188),2);      //change Map to this coordinate (best try to center of earth)

      }
    }

//Run this function when "Plot Points" is submitted
function plot(){

    //plotAddress("tooltip","city, state","link to image with extension", iconWidth, iconHeight); *iconWidth and iconHeight, not necessary
    //plotAddress("Factory", "New York, NY","icons/_firstaid.png", 15, 15);
    //plotAddress("Factory", "New York, NY","icons/_firstaid.png", 15, 15);

    //plotLatLong("tooltip",latitude, longitude, "link to image with extension", iconWidth, iconHeight);
    //plotLatLong("FELDBACH, Switzerland",47.66667,8.98333,"icons/_mainroad.png", 15, 15);
    //plotLatLong("Lab",48.83777, 10.0933, "icons/_firstaid.png", 15, 15);

    //draw line
    //GPolyline(whereLatLongFrom, whereLatLongTo, lineColor, lineWeight, lineOpacity)
    //var polyline1= new GPolyline([new GLatLng(33.8796,-117.8951),new GLatLng(34.780607,-106.711537)], "#000000", 3,0.9);map.addOverlay(polyline1);

    //draw circle
    //drawCircle(whereLatLong, radiusMiles, numPointsInCircle, lineColor, lineWeight, lineOpacity, fillColor, fillOpacity)
    //drawCircle(new GLatLng(42.2773088, -83.7350464), 600, 100,"#00ff00",3,0.9,"#00ff00",0.5);
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------paste after this line


plotLatLong("Pratt",41.7633,-88.2900,"icons/factory.png", 30, 30);



drawCircle(new GLatLng(31.2,-112.3),358,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);
drawCircle(new GLatLng(32.6742,-101.2789),102,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);
drawCircle(new GLatLng(42.95,-120.2),29,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);
drawCircle(new GLatLng(42.2783,-114.1589),10,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);
drawCircle(new GLatLng(32.95,-80.2),10,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);
drawCircle(new GLatLng(34.9347,-104.9119),10,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);
drawCircle(new GLatLng(29.2,-100.5),10,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);
drawCircle(new GLatLng(29.2,-110.5),10,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);
drawCircle(new GLatLng(31.2,-112.3),10,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);
drawCircle(new GLatLng(32.9,-119.8),10,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);
drawCircle(new GLatLng(36.4,-118.4),10,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);
drawCircle(new GLatLng(45.517,-73.667),10,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);
drawCircle(new GLatLng(51.045,-114.0581),10,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);
drawCircle(new GLatLng(51.9,-0.2),10,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);
drawCircle(new GLatLng(31.2,-121.5),44,50,"#000000",2,1,"#FF0000",0.75);



//--------------------------------------------------------------------------complete paste before this line
}
function updateZoom()
{
  plot();
  var latlngbounds = new GLatLngBounds( );
  for ( var i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++ )
  {
    latlngbounds.extend( latlng[ i ] );
    //document.write(latlng[i]);
    //alert (numPoints);
  }
  map.setCenter( latlngbounds.getCenter( ), map.getBoundsZoomLevel( latlngbounds ) );   
}


    //Function gets and plots long, lat based on city, state input
    function plotAddress(toolTip,address, iconLink, iconWidth, iconHeight) {
      if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.getLatLng(
         address,
          function(point) {
            if (!point) {
              alert(address + " not found", 15, 15);
            } else {

              //create custom icon required variables and link variable to icon link
              var customIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
              customIcon.image = iconLink;
              //customIconSize if necessary
              if(iconWidth){
                customIcon.iconSize = new GSize(iconWidth, iconHeight);
                customIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(iconWidth/2,iconHeight);
                customIcon.shadow = "";
              }else{} //else do nothing to change the icon size

              markerOptions = { icon:customIcon, draggable:true}

              //create marker
              var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions); 
              //add event to marker when clicked
              GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {  
              //When clicked, open an Info Window  
              marker.openInfoWindowHtml(toolTip);  
              });  
              //plot marker
              map.addOverlay(marker);
              //add to arrary for best fit zoom
              latlng[numPoints] = point;
              numPoints++;
            }
          }
        );
      }
    }
    function plotLatLong(toolTip, latIN,lngIN, iconLink, iconWidth, iconHeight) {
        //create custom icon,required variables and link variable to icon link
        var customIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
        customIcon.image = iconLink;
        //customIconSize if necessary
        if(iconWidth){
        customIcon.iconSize = new GSize(iconWidth, iconHeight);
        customIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(iconWidth/2,iconHeight);
        customIcon.shadow = "";
        }else{} //else do nothing to change the icon size

        markerOptions = {icon:customIcon, draggable:true, }

        //assign Lat and Long
        var latlngIN = new GLatLng(latIN, lngIN);   

        //create marker
        var marker = new GMarker(latlngIN, markerOptions);  

        //add event to marker when clicked
        GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {  
        //When clicked, open an Info Window  
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(toolTip);  
        });  
        //plot marker
        latlng[numPoints] = latlngIN;
        //add to arrary for best fit zoom
        numPoints++;
        map.addOverlay(marker);                     
    }
    function drawCircle(whereLatLong, radiusMiles, numPointsInCircle, lineColor, lineWeight, lineOpacity, fillColor, fillOpacity){
        poly = [] ; 
        var lat = whereLatLong.lat() ;
        var lng = whereLatLong.lng() ;
        var d2r = Math.PI/180 ;                // degrees to radians
        var r2d = 180/Math.PI ;                // radians to degrees
        var Clat = (radiusMiles/3963) * r2d ;      //  using 3963 as earth's radius
        var Clng = Clat/Math.cos(lat*d2r);

        //Add each point in the circle
        for (var i = 0 ; i < numPointsInCircle ; i++)
        {
            var theta = Math.PI * (i / (numPointsInCircle / 2)) ;
            Cx = lng + (Clng * Math.cos(theta)) ;
            Cy = lat + (Clat * Math.sin(theta)) ;
            poly.push(new GLatLng(Cy,Cx)) ;
        }

        //Add the first point to complete the circle
        poly.push(poly[0]) ;

        //Create a circle
        circle = new GPolygon(poly, lineColor, lineWeight, lineOpacity, fillColor, fillOpacity) ;
        map.addOverlay(circle) ;
    }

    // If the map position is out of range, move it back
    function checkBounds() {
        // Perform the check and return if OK
        if (allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
          return;
        }
        // It`s not OK, so find the nearest allowed point and move there
        var C = map.getCenter();
        var X = C.lng();
        var Y = C.lat();

        var AmaxX = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lng();
        var AmaxY = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lat();
        var AminX = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lng();
        var AminY = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

        if (X < AminX) {X = AminX;}
        if (X > AmaxX) {X = AmaxX;}
        if (Y < AminY) {Y = AminY;}
        if (Y > AmaxY) {Y = AmaxY;}
        //alert ("Restricting "+Y+" "+X);
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(Y,X));
    }
    </script>
  </head>

<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
<input type="button" style="background-color:red" value="Clear Page" onClick="location.reload(true)" />
<input type="submit" style="background-color:lightgreen" value="Plot Points" onClick="plot();" />
<input type="submit" style="background-color:lightblue" value="Zoom - Fit" onClick="updateZoom();" />
<BR><BR>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1400px; height: 880px"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using the API v2, which was deprecated in 2010, and hasn't worked at all since about last November (if it does you're really seeing a bastardised version of v3, which will have reduced functionality).  You should rewrite the whole thing to use API v3 before tackling anything else.  Please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3

Comment: It is really easy to make a "blank" map type in v3, see [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes), [this example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-base) is pretty close (don't display the coordinates and remove the tile borders)

Comment: okay, I tried rewriting to v3. I can turn the map to invisible ({ visibility: 'off' }... but I can't get the shape overlays to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, I switched the V3, but can't get the shapes to display:

Comment: What does that code look like? Can you provide a fiddle or a link that shows the problem? I have seen issues with styling the map to turn everything off (which is why I suggested the custom map with blank tiles).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple styled maps</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var map;
var brooklyn = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6743890, -100.9455);

var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';
function initialize() {

  var featureOpts = [
    {
      stylers: [
        { hue: '#736F6E' },
        { visibility: 'simplified' },
      ]
    },
    {
      elementType: 'labels',
      stylers: [
        { visibility: 'off' }
      ]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'water',
      stylers: [
        { color: '#736F6E' }
      ]
    }
  ];

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: brooklyn,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
    },
    mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  var styledMapOptions = {
    name: 'Custom Style'
  };

  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);

  map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);
  drawCircle(new google.maps.LatLng(31.2,-121.5),300,50,"#2D2D2D",2,1,"#2D2D2D",0.75);
}

function drawCircle(whereLatLong, radiusMiles, numPointsInCircle, lineColor, lineWeight, lineOpacity, fillColor, fillOpacity){
        poly = [] ; 
        var lat = whereLatLong.lat() ;
        var lng = whereLatLong.lng() ;
        var d2r = Math.PI/180 ;                // degrees to radians
        var r2d = 180/Math.PI ;                // radians to degrees
        var Clat = (radiusMiles/3963) * r2d ;      //  using 3963 as earth's radius
        var Clng = Clat/Math.cos(lat*d2r);

        //Add each point in the circle
        for (var i = 0 ; i < numPointsInCircle ; i++)
        {
            var theta = Math.PI * (i / (numPointsInCircle / 2)) ;
            Cx = lng + (Clng * Math.cos(theta)) ;
            Cy = lat + (Clat * Math.sin(theta)) ;
            poly.push(new google.maps.LatLng(Cy,Cx)) ;
        }

        //Add the first point to complete the circle
        poly.push(poly[0]) ;

        // Create a circle
        circle = new google.maps.Polygon({
                          paths: poly,
                          strokeColor: lineColor,
                          strokeWeight: lineWeight,
                          strokeOpacity: lineOpacity,
                          fillColor: fillColor,
                          fillOpacity: fillOpacity
                        });
        circle.setMap(map);             
    }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Your code still uses v2 methods. For eg: new GLatLng ==> new google.maps.LatLng, new GPolygon ==> new google.maps.Polygon, map.addOverlay(circle) ==> circle.setMap(map); Also you were calling drawCircle in the wrong place. See corrected code. Its works for me